# Scraping with Python returns NONE

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape info from a site that is using java script overlayed on google maps. Using inspector I can clearly see the data I want to recover, but I have been unsuccessful thus far.

I have tried the following; requests, Beautiful soup with PyQt (Sentdex example) - this works for his example but I can't get it to work for mijn. See code... and I've tried many others. Any ideas? Thanks.

[image]

```py
    import bs4 as bs
    import sys
    import urllib.request
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl

    class Page(QWebEnginePage):
        def __init__(self, url):
            self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
            QWebEnginePage.__init__(self)
            self.html = ''
            self.loadFinished.connect(self._on_load_finished)
            self.load(QUrl(url))
            self.app.exec_()

        def _on_load_finished(self):
            self.html = self.toHtml(self.Callable)
            print('Load finished')

        def Callable(self, html_str):
            self.html = html_str
            self.app.quit()


    def main():
        page = Page('https://inzameling.spaarnelanden.nl/')
        soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(page.html, 'lxml')
        js_test = soup.find('div', class_='infoBoxValue')
        print(js_test)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Are you clicking or hovering manually to get that information? because the information may be getting fetched on demand on a event

Comment: clicking. The information shows when you click the small garbage containers.

Comment: FYI:Code is from contributor 'Ayanda Khanyile' post of solution PyQt5 updated from PyQt4.